# What does the "function" tδ(t) look like?

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

So my question came out of considering functions involving the unit step function and their derivatives. I'm learning about Laplace transforms right now, if that helps provide context. So here is what I think so far. If I've made any mistakes please let me know.

First of all, we can easily say that for any value other than $t=0$, $tδ(t) =0$ since $δ(t) = 0$ and $t$ is finite. However, for $t=0$ things are more interesting. $δ(t)$ is infinite while $t=0$. I'm sure this could be treated as some sort of limit of a function that approaches the dirac delta function. However, my question arose in a different context.

Let us take the function: $$f(t) = t[u(t)-u(t-1)] + u(t-1)$$

The "generalized" derivative (I'm not sure exactly how it formally got generalized that way) of the unit step function/heaviside function is the dirac delta function. So if we take the derivative of our function we should get: $$f'(t)=[u(t)-u(t-1)]+t[δ(t)-δ(t-1)]+δ(t-1)$$$$f'(t) = [u(t) - u(t-1)] + tδ(t) + (1-t)δ(t-1)$$

However, we also know that from the piecewise definition that: $$f'(t) = u(t)-u(t-1)$$

If these derivatives are to be equal, then $tδ(t)$ and $(1-t)δ(t-1)$ (which are both instances of the same thing) must equal $0$ or be additive inverses. Based on other experiences, I believe they should be $0$. Is this correct? If so, how can this be formally proven?

Comment: I know it's not a real function, I just don't know what it actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add to Beta's answer, the statement

$$t\delta(t)=0$$

is valid in a distributional sense because of the following. We know that the Dirac delta has the property

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\delta(t-a)dt=f(a)$$

for any test function $f$. If we consider $t\delta(t)$ as a distribution as well we have by selecting $a=0$ and evaluating as above,

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)t\delta(t)dt=f(t)t|_{t=0}=f(0)\cdot 0 = 0$$

for every test function $f$. Hence it makes sense to conclude that $t\delta(t)=0$.

Comment: It make sense, but could we not just pick any arbitrary finite number to be the value of tδ(t) at 0 and the integral would still be valid?

Answer (score 1):

There is a well know property of the Dirac Delta Distribution, called "distributional product". It states that

$$x\delta(x) = 0$$

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)